# How to update Bootstrap (and use LESS) in a Meteor app

Tags: meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3, meteorite

I have followed the instructions given in the readmes of both `bootstrap3-less` and `meteor-bootstrap-3` meteorite packages, but it seems there are steps missing.

Could someone explain, to an inexperienced developer, exactly (step-by-step) how to 'upgrade' from the Meteor package `bootstrap` to Bootstrap 3 (preferably with LESS but not essential)?

Some specific queries:

- Should I uninstall the standard `bootstrap` package first?
- Where does one reference the new .less or css files (or is that done as part of the mrt package)?
- Any other best practises

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is almost just like you actually said. Assuming your are on linux/mac, make sure you are at project root directory and then

```
$ mrt remove bootstrap
$ mrt add less
$ mrt add bootstrap3-less
$ mkdir -p client/styles
$ touch client/styles/my-styles.less
$ sed -i '$ a\@import "/packages/bootstrap3-less/bootstrap.import.less";' client/styles/my-styles.less
$ cd public && ln -s ../packages/bootstrap3-less/lib/fonts ./
```

That's it. For further customization and advanced usage, take a look at the official readme at https://github.com/simison/bootstrap3-less

Also, search atmosphere for keyword *bootstrap* and you'll find lots of packages that you can include in your project.

Also, packages get updated from time to time.

Therefore, once in while, make sure you run in your project root directory:

```
$ mrt update
```

Or if you are cloning your project from git to a new workspace, you need to install third party  packages first:

```
$ mrt install
```

Comment: In regards to the last last line of your script, make sure you first remove/move the `/public/fonts/` folder if it currently exists in your project, otherwise the symbolic link `ln` will fail with a `file exists` error.

Comment: This worked, many thanks. Can you explain what's happening in the last step? From Googling it seem you're creating a symbolic link to the fonts folder within a folder called public at the project root? How come?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Normally when meteor bundles up package resources for production deployment, it grabs js and css files from the packages and concatenates them to use either on the server, the client or both. But img/font etc static assets don't get copied over to the public folder, they stay at a relative path from the packages root folder. Including a symbolic link ensures that when the app is deployed with production config, the static assets are accessible from within the public directory as a base root.